# iterate and display data from json

Tags: jquery, json

i have my json object in the php file as

```
echo json_encode(array('uname'=>$fname,'Oname'=>$pi['name'],'osize'=>$size));
```

iam trying to loop through it on the client sidewith the following jquery,but it displays only one record in the list.how can i improve this to work well

```
function work(i,fly,response){
                 _outfilenames=[];
        //$.each(response, function() {


         _outfilenames.push("<li>" +"<div ><a href='#'            data-name='"+response.uname +"'><img src='stop.png' ></a></div>"+ "<span class='filename'>" +response.Oname+ "</span> "  +"<span class='details'>size:</strong>"+response.size +" </span>" +"</li>");

        $(_outfilenames.join('')).appendTo("#flist");
```

the response  is fine and when i check it  like this

```
names=[];names.push(response.Oname);
```

surely gets the data.but why does the outfilenames variable only give me one list.i have tried using each but still ican't get this to work.please help

here is my updated code:

```
function work(i,fly,response){
var cookedJSON=[];cookedJSON.push({ uname : response.uname , Oname : response.Oname , osize :response.osize });
         _outfilenames=[];
$.each(cookedJSON, function(i,arr) {

      _outfilenames.push("<li id='group_0_file_"+i+"'class='image-list'>" +"<div class='controls' title='remove file'><a href='#' class='image-list' data-filename='"+arr.uname +"'><img src='stop.png' ></a></div>"+   "<span class='filename'>" +arr.Oname+ "</span> "  +"<span class='details'>size:</strong>"+arr.osize +" </span>" +"</li>");//}
});  // close each()
$(_outfilenames.join('')).appendTo(f_list);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, don't see issues on first look. maybe need to see you json. + I don't see how you iterate the list.

here is my sample http://jsfiddle.net/fLTxK/

just for test:

```
var cookedJSON = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i+=1)
{
    cookedJSON.push({ uname : 'uname' + i, Oname : 'Oname' + i, size : 'size' + i});
}
```

and the code:

```
var _outfilenames = [], response = '';
for (i = 0; i < 10; i+=1)
{
    response = cookedJSON[i];
_outfilenames.push("<li>" +"<div ><a href='#'            data-name='"+response.uname +"'><img src='stop.png' ></a></div>"+ "<span class='filename'>" +response.Oname+ "</span> "  +"<span class='details'>size:</strong>"+response.size +" </span>" +"</li>");
}
$(_outfilenames.join('')).appendTo("body");
```

As plus , I will say, I don't prefer hard way of making templates, use engines like Mustache or whatever. but it's up to you

Comment: thanks eugene .your solution  has helped me come to a better way of joining all the data from php into one array like this: cookedJSON=[];cookedJSON.push({ uname : response.uname , Oname : response.Oname , osize : response.osize }); i didn't know that before

Comment: Why is my code displaying only two values yet i expect around 4-5.

Comment: there it ie Mr Eugene

Comment: let's do that way: post your code to jsfiddle, where 'response' variable will be your JSON from php.  I'll take a look then